# How to save data and display it when I have some constraints

Tags: c#, data-binding, data-structures, datagridview

Its hard to specify a title...

I breaking my head to figure out this problem,

I have packet that including "data" "time" and "id".

I need to save it in some data structure and display only the data in some way on the form (maybe a datagridview),
but I need the ability to get the rest packet info (time and id) when I'm clicking on the displayed data.

For example:

0110      1110      0101    0001

The first data id is 9 and the time is 2222. When I click on the first data (0110) I need to display (lets say in lable on the form) id = 9 and time = 2222.

One more thing, the data must be displayed like the way in the above example (in row with space between the data.

**Edit:**
I forgot something important.
If I use databinding there is option to change the data location on the grid (based on some packet info) from some cell/row to another? if not maybe databinding its not good here.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: what does your program do so far, and where are stuck? Show us the code you already have!

Comment: @Doc I can't show the code. I can explain why in pm if u want. I dont need the exactly code, just the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, using a DataGridView, try this:

```
// DataGridView

Databing the data source to the DataGridView (use a list of your packet for that)

---------------------------------
| DATA 1 | DATA 2 | DATA 3 | ... (Header)
---------------------------------
|  0110  |  1110  |  0101  | ... (Data)
---------------------------------
```

Add a event handler to the DataGridView CellContentClick, just like this:

```
private void myDataGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1) // A row and cell was selected
    {
        var packet = myDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Packet;
        if (packet != null)
        {
            // Display packet information
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks marco(?). but if my list is the data source how the datagrid will know to display only the data?

Comment: You can set the columns that you want to display on datagridview. Just define the columns at design time and set the property AutoGenerateColumns (i guess thats the name) to "false".

Answer (score 0):

Make your packet a class where data, time and id are private members and `DisplayData` is a public property. To access the content of the private members from outside, use properties with the  `[Browsable(false)]` attribute:

```
public class Packet
{
    private int data, time, id;

    public string DisplayData {get {return FunctionToFormatDataToMyNeeds(data); }}
    // ...

    [Browsable(false)]
    public int Time{get{return time;}}
}
```

Bind a list of those objects to the data source of your DataGridView.